# Variable assignment in expressions

Tags: python, c

Here is my code to generate values in the fibonnacci sequence below 10,000,000.

```
  3 fibs = [1,1]
  4 while((x = fibs[-1] + fibs[-2]) <= 10000000):
  5     fibs.append(x)
```

I attempted to do C-style assignment of x in the while loop's condition. Unfortunately, python told me that it's a syntax error. What is the simplest solution?

Comment: What tutorial are you using to learn Python?  Where have you seen Python code like this?  What part of the language manual implied that this could possibly work?  What made you think this was legal syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[In Python, assignment is not an expression, and therefore has no value.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Value_of_an_assignment)

The simplest solution is to do the assignment in the first part of the loop:

```
fibs=[1,1]
while fibs[-1] <= 10000000:
   fibs.append(fibs[-1] + fibs[-2])
```

Comment: Dammit, I like this one better than my own.

Comment: Resurrecting this, note that assignment expressions are soon to become a thing: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/

Answer (score 3):

Basically:

```
fibs = [1]
x = 1

while(x <= 10000000):
  fibs.append(x)
  # It is not possible for "fibs" not to have
  # at least two elements by now
  x = fibs[-1] + fibs[-2]
```

(It was, in fact, one of the design goals of Python to avoid mixing expressions and assignments like C — that's why there's no `x++`, `x--`, which is also a semi-FAQ.)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for not allowing assignment in Python expressions is a common, hard-to-find bug in those other languages, caused by this construct.

Please check
http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import imap, islice, takewhile
import operator
fibs = [1, 1]
for x in takewhile(partial(operator.ge, 10000000),
                   imap(operator.add, fibs, islice(fibs, 1, None))):
    fibs.append(x)
```

Oh wait, you said "simplest"?  Nevermind then.