# Is there a way to use one copy of simulated random variable in a line?

Tags: python, expression, variable-assignment

Is there a way to use one copy of simulated random variable in one line in Python (without defining a new function)?

For example, if I need to evaluate `f(x) = x + sin(x)` for normal random variable, I will write `x = norm.rvs()` then the next line `x + sin(x)`. If I do `norm.rvs() + sin(norm.rvs())` this is equivalent to simulating two independent copies of random variables, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: Not prior to the implementation of [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

Comment: ... and the scheduled release date of version 3.8 is 2019-OCT-20 (PEP 569)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671990/nested-lambda-statements-when-sorting-lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable assignment in expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161578/variable-assignment-in-expressions)